# Embed ASP.NET application in VB6

Tags: asp.net, vb6

Does anybody have a clue how I might embed an ASP.NET 3.5 app inside a Visual Basic 6 application?

My other option is to provide a hyperlink inside the VB6 application that will open the ASP.NET app.....BUT I would prefer to embed the ASP.NET app within a tab control in VB6 if at all possible.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the auto-login to the .net app (assuming it's ASP.net) I would have the vb6 application login process write a session GUID to the database, and use it as a get or post variable when building a link to the .net application.

On the ASP.NET side, modify your MembershipProvider to honor a guid and username as evidence of successful authentication to the vb6 app.

There may be some additional security precautions you should take depending on how guarded your environment needs to be.

Answer (score 2):

Realistically, your best option is probably to use the Web Browser control on a new tab, and point that at your ASP.NET application.

For auto-login, you SHOULD be able to have users login once. You'll probably need to enable a "remember me" feature in your ASP.NET application.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a terrible idea.

I think you should give more background on the situation so alternatives can be suggested.

**EDIT**: You say the VB6 app cannot be rewritten... but can it be edited? Depending on the complexity of the functionality in the ASP.Net app you could alter the ASP.Net app to include a web service and access that functionality from the VB6 app.

Comment: Client has a 9 year old VB6 app that is mission critical.  Users are in it all day and they want to be able to access a new ASP.NET app without opening additional windows.  They also want to be logged in to the ASP.NET app automatically accessed from the VB6 app.  I know, sounds crazy but rewriting VB6 is not an option right now.

Comment: I don't think you're really wanting to host an ASP.NET app, let IIS do it. You need a browser control like Nate said, and then you'll have to add a bunch of browser functionality. If it's mission critical, keep the budget down and convince the user to work in a popup.

Answer (score 1):

It'd be a two part process.

Create a .NET library to host asp.net, http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/aspnetruntime/aspnetruntime.asp.

Then use interopt to launch the library. Sounds like a really bad idea though.